# What is the equivalent of the HttpResponseBase.BufferOutput property in ASP.NET Core 2?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am in the process of converting a large .NET Framework project to a .NET Core project, and I have come across the following code:

```
public class ContentStreamingResult : ActionResult {

    private Action<Stream> _onExecuteAction;

    public ContentStreamingResult(Action<Stream> onExecuteAction) {
        _onExecuteAction = onExecuteAction;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) {
        var httpContext = context.HttpContext;
        httpContext.Response.BufferOutput = false;
        _onExecuteAction(httpContext.Response.OutputStream);
    }
}
```

There is no `BufferOutput` property on the `HttpResponse` class in .NET Core.

What is the equivalent of the `HttpResponseBase.BufferOutput` property in ASP.NET Core 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For enabling `Buffering` in Asp.Net Core, you could use `UseResponseBuffering` middleware in `Startup` like below:

```
app.UseResponseBuffering();
```

After applying the `Buffering Middleware`, if you want to disable buffer for specific requests, you could try code below:

```
var bufferingFeature = httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpBufferingFeature>();
bufferingFeature?.DisableResponseBuffering();
```

Comment: And if you want to enable response buffering for only one request (e.g. streaming image bytes to the response?)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `IHttpResponseBodyFeature` for response buffer or `IHttpRequestBodyFeature` for request buffer.

```
 httpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseBodyFeature>().DisableBuffering()
```

Comment: This should be the right answer as `IHttpBufferingFeature` is old and obsoleted